# Нужна ссылка на второй класс в другом скрипте

Tags: c#, save

Всем привет, реализовывал в игре функцию сохранения данных, по гайдам сделал скрипт SaveSerial, в котором добавил класс SaveData. Теперь не могу сделать ссылку из другого скрипта на нужный мне метод из класса SaveData.

```
public class SaveSerial : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int coinSave;

    private void Start()
    {

    }
}

[Serializable]

class SaveData
{
    public int savedCoin;

    public void SaveGame()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/MySaveData.dat");
        SaveData data = new SaveData();
        data.savedCoin = SaveSerial.coinSave;
        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы использовать его в другой сборке, нужно классу SaveData добавить модификатор public.

Comment: Я добавлял классу SaveData public, я хочу знать код по которому смогу сделать ссылку на этот класс, так как через GetComponent не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Короче я просто передела сохранение на более здоровое, как мне кажется, я не обращался ко второму классу из вне, а просто перекидывал обращение из первого класса

```
 public class SaveLoadManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    string filePath;
    public GameObject countCoin;

    public CoinManager script;
    private int coinCount;

    public void Start()
    {
        filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Saved.gamesave";
        script = countCoin.GetComponent<CoinManager>();
    }

    public void SaveGame()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

        Save save = new Save();

        save.SaveCoin(coinCount, script);

        bf.Serialize(fs, save);

        fs.Close();
    }

    public void LoadGame()
    {

    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Save
{
    public void SaveCoin(int coinCount, CoinManager script)
    {
        script.Return(coinCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SaveSerial : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int coinSave;
    private SaveData data1;
            
    private void Start()
    {
        data1.SaveGame(); //вызываешь метод
    }
}
    
[Serializable]        
public class SaveData // обязательно public
{
    public static SaveData saveData { get; set; } // делаешь класс статичным get и set на своё усмотрение приватизируй
    public int savedCoin;
    
    public void SaveGame()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/MySaveData.dat");
        SaveData data = new SaveData();
        data.savedCoin = SaveSerial.coinSave;
        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Скажешь потом заработало ли :)